# Aws datapipeline record seperator issue

Tags: postgresql

i have a file whose new line charachter is "\r\n" but while inserting in datapipeline it gives issues , as they have no identification for such record seperator, all of your inputs are required . Please

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned about error log I can't conclude but most probably this problem is not because of data pipeline but what target database you are using.           If you are using Redshift as a target database please check below link. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-syntax-overview-data-format